# C++ Constructor initializer for arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

I am using C++11 and I want to initialize an array of objects in the initializer list of a constructor. I have found a related question but it doesn't meet my needs:

- I would like the class of the objects of the array to be non-copyable.
- I would like the class of the objects of the array to have a destructor.

Compiles:

```
class foo {
  public:
    foo(int& n) : i(n) {}
    //~foo() {} // If uncommented, it doesn't compile.

  private:
    int& i;

    // Disable copy constructor and assignment operator.
    foo(const foo&) = delete;
    foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete;
};

class bar {
  public:
    bar()
      : f{{i}, {i}}
    {
    }

  private:
    foo f[2];
    int i;
};
```

Doesn't compile:

```
class foo {
  public:
    foo(int& n) : i(n) {}
    ~foo() {} // If uncommented, it doesn't compile.


  private:
    int& i;

    // Disable copy constructor and assignment operator.
    foo(const foo&) = delete; // If commented out, it compiles.
    foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete;
};

class bar {
  public:
    bar()
      : f{{i}, {i}}
    {
    }

  private:
    foo f[2];
    int i;
};
```

I am using g++ and get the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘bar::bar()’:
main.cpp:10:5: error: ‘foo::foo(const foo&)’ is private
main.cpp:17:19: error: within this context
main.cpp:17:19: error: use of deleted function ‘foo::foo(const foo&)’
main.cpp:10:5: error: declared here
```

Why does it make a difference if the object is non-copyable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known GCC bug [63707](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63707) with status `NEW`. The same code works fine in [CLANG](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c083614dc51b06a).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. First time that it is compiler's fault and not my fault :)